# How to make one list without a sublist from a string in Python

Tags: python, jython

I'm trying to create a list without any sublists from a string with white space in Python? For example:

```
s = "Hello world"
L = s.split()
print L
>>>> ["H","e","l","l","o"," ","w","o","r","l","d"]
```

What I want to avoid it this:

```
s = "Hello world"
L = s.split()
print L
>>>> ["Hello", "world"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `list(s)` will return the list of characters in string `s`.

```
>>> s = "Hello world"
>>> list(s)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>>
```

Comment: I guess I should also mention that I'm using Jython. Do you know if the `list()` function is available in Jython?

Comment: @MatthewHelmer, `list` is a type, not a function, but, it **is** an absolutely mandatory built-in in **every** version of Python, including of course Jython, so you can call it without worries.

Comment: @MatthewHelmer, hoping for an "accept" then (click the checkmark outline to the left of the question, when enough time has passed from your question that stackoverflow will let you do that)...!-)